# How to make wordpress " kitsune theme" live

Tags: wordpress

I have download kitsune wordpress theme. But i am getting issue .

How to make wordpress kitsune theme live .

I have purchase this theme . The site is running when i am login through wp login but not working when i am not login .

Please help me out . because i am unable to make this site live.

Comment: I don't see any way we can help you since we have not any links, or any reference or screenshot available to see and look in to your problem. If you wish to solve the issue please provide us some more details.

Answer (score 1):

It might be **maintenance mode** is **on** please read the documentation or approach the support forum through **themeforest** or where you have purchased it.

If you still have the same issue, it may need to look into the your site and admin section.